What is the cross reference of OT to Mtt 24:37-38?
We read in Mtt 24: 37-38  (KJV):

As  the days of Noah were, so  shall also the coming of the Son of man be. For as in the days that were before the flood they were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, until the day that Noah entered into the ark,

By saying " marrying and giving in marriage" Jesus may have meant that people at the time of Noah were busy planning for posterity without foreseeing  the   impending end of their mirthful world.
< Genesis 6 speaks of 'sons of God'entering into marriage contract with 'daughters of men'. Luke 3 shows Noah having lived after a few generations after Adam. That would imply that introductory paragraph of Gen 6 referring to marriages was  alluding to a time much before that of Noah.  My question therefore is: Which OT narrative did Jesus have in mind while referring to marriages in Noah's time ?

There were 8 generations inbetween Adam and Noah. Seth, Enosh, Kenan, Mahalalel, Jared, Enoch, Methuselah, and Lamech (Noah's father.) Bear in mind that, back then,  age-spans were phenomenal, being either 900+ or 800+ years (though Enoch 'only' lived 365 years.) This means that the average lifespan before the tower of Babel was 912 years (excluding Enoch); the average lifespan after Babel dropped to 185 years.
This has a bearing on the question, as I see it: What did Jesus have in mind when he spoke of people marrying? Only those marriages at the time of Noah, or of marriages long, long before the time of Noah?
Yet, could not the answer be ALL the marriages from Genesis 6:1 right up to the time God shut Noah, his family and all the cargo into the Ark, 7 days before the deluge began?  After all, God had been enduring the build-up of evil in the Earth from Cain right through to Noah's day, when Noah was the only one who found grace in God's eyes. That time was around 1,100 years. By then, the wickedness of humanity was so great and so vile, God's patience ended and he took drastic action. Note, too, that Genesis shows polygamy from an early stage, so not just 1 marriage per man during his eight- or nine-hundred year lifespan. Many marriages to many women seemed to be the norm.
Jesus spoke of what seemed to be a preoccupation with pre-flood mankind - eating, drinking, and marrying. Marriage usually entails feasting and drinking, but nobody needs to wait for a marriage to be obsessed with eating and drinking. Gluttony and drunkenness may have been in Jesus' mind too. But the point of real significance is that "they took no note" until it was too late.
As Jesus was using that fact of history to warn of the same situation just before he returns unexpectedly, it hardly matters if he had only one particular generation in mind when he warned us in Matthew 24:37-38, or whether he was thinking of all the generations from Adam to Noah. What is going on in our generation today? Are we so caught up with carnal matters like eating, drinking and marrying that we are taking no note of the appalling growth of wickedness world-wide in our generation? There's nothing wrong with eating, drinking and marrying, as such, but the way wicked people who do not fear God over-indulge their physical appetites (including sexual ones) should be our concern.
I digress from the question. To answer, Jesus knew of every generation from Adam to Noah, so it seems likely he was thinking of all of them when he spoke that warning. The narrative was not limited to just one particular generation. However, the point made in the question, that "Jesus may have meant that people at the time of Noah were busy planning for posterity without foreseeing the impending end of their mirthful world" is absolutely true. His prophecy warns of living selfish, materialistic lives. And that tragic fact of carnal humanity is as true then as it is in our generation today.

Thanks, Anne for the wonderful answer . The nuance of my question lies in the final line. Was Jesus quoting from OT when he spoke of marriages of Noah's time. Of course,he knew even those happenings which were not recorded in the scriptures.At the same time he was adept in quoting from OT like a scholarly Jew.

Matthew 24:38 NIV

For in the days before the flood, people were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, up to the day Noah entered the ark;

The phrase 'eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage', can be understood in contemporary terms as 'partying'. In my opinion, this phrase should be taken as an idiom rather than a direct reference to any Old Testament scripture.
The closest usage of this concept can be found in Jeremiah 16:8-9 NIV

8 “And do not enter a house where there is feasting and sit down to eat and drink. 9 For this is what the Lord Almighty, the God of Israel, says: Before your eyes and in your days I will bring an end to the sounds of joy and gladness and to the voices of bride and bridegroom in this place.

The context of Jeremiah 16:8-9 is set on the brink of the destruction of Jerusalem. The people who would fall with Jerusalem were those indulged in feasting. This mirrors the mentality during the time of Noah, where those who mocked Noah prioritized their effort on 'partying'.

Which Narrative Did Jesus Have in Mind?There is absolutely no connection between the OT story of the marriage between the Sons of God and the daughter of men. Jesus is specific in mentioning only the Noahic era and the impending flood.
It has been customary in recent time to try to find allusions to all sorts of evil conduct and wickedness implications in Jesus's wording here in Matthew 24. But that is a "fool's errand." Oxham's rule applies here: the simplest meaning is the best interpretation!
Jesus is merely listing normal activities of every day life on earth and in every society. And the following verses that Jesus gave, clearly explained His point. The return of Christ at the Second Coming was to happen unawares! There were to be no signs to point to an impending ending.
The posted question stopped the quoted verse (Mtt. 24:38) with the comma, which was the middle of a sentence! This is a common mistake that readers who want to understand the text commit. In order to understand the Bible one must ignore the artificial numbering of verses, and read on. The whole sentence---with the rest of the context---quite often explains the meaning Jesus intended to portray.

And knew not until the flood came, and took them all away; so shall also the Coming of the Son of Man be. (24:39)...Watch therefore for you know not what hour your Lord does come. (24:42)

Marrying, dining out, and the preaching of the Gospel (by Noah), is the same social climate that is to describe the end of the world. (Second Coming) These reference have nothing to do with "divorce, adultery, boozing, gluttony, false cult, ad nauseum." Normalcy is the only intent of Jesus's warning.
Like one of the Apostles noted in his letter, it is so normal that some will ask, "When is His coming? Where is the time of His coming?" Nobody will have any indication of the End.

And saying, "Where is the promise of His coming? For since the fathers fell asleep, all things continue as they were from the beginning of Creation." (2 Peter 3:4; normal times described)
But the Day of the LORD will come as a thief in the night in which the heavens will pass away... (2 Peter 3:10)


But of the times and seasons, brothers, you have no need that I write unto you. For yourselves know perfectly that the Day of the Lord so cometh as a thief in the night. For when they shall say, "Peace and safety, then sudden destruction comes upon them, as travail on a woman with child... (1 Thessalonians 5:1-3)

To prove that this is the correct interpretation when Jesus referenced Noah's day, Jesus gave not one more, but several more illustrations beyond the illustration of Noah's society.  Watch for you know not the hour!  Jesus said this over and over again! (Matthew 24:42,44,50, 25:13)
Just as you don't know when a thief comes...just as you don't know when the landlord will show up...just as you cannot know when the bridegroom arrives...so also you will not know when that day will happen!  No signs of the times. No end-time signs.
Further considerationsWhen modern commentators mention evil things like license or debauchery or gluttony or lethargy---or authoritarian governments---or marriage between sons of god to daughters of men (however that is interpreted), they are ignoring the historical fact that these have happened continuously in history during the rise and fall of human nations. Evil conduct could not be a "sign of the end" because they are endless, continually happening in man's history.
It makes more sense to interpret Jesus's warning as normal times that catch men unawares. Christians will not know either---BUT they will be prepared, living holy lives, and watching upward with joyous expectation for their Savior (King) to return! (1 Thessalonians 5:4-11)

Thanks ray grant, for the new perspective. But most versions of Mtt 24:39 gives a picture of the people having been destroyed or 'swept  away', implying that they were in deed wicked. If you feel that wicked people of Noah's time were going about with daily chores, and that God wanted them dead, one feels that you will elucidate.


Kadalikatt Joseph Sibichan - Jesus's own words deal with the suddenness of the Second Coming, not the wickedness of the people. Both believers and unbelievers  (wicked people) will not know the time.  It is true that there will be wicked people in the future, just as there were wicked people in Noah's day (there were also believers too, just as there will be believers in the future).  But ""wickedness" was not the point of Jesus's message; suddenness was!  Wicked people do eat and drink, marry, etc. But the point is that during these common times, Christ will come without warning as a thief.


Marrying and giving in marriage:
Genesis 6:1-4 speaks of them multiplying on the face of the earth which Jesus may have had in mind:

6 Now it came to pass, when men began to multiply on the face of the earth, and daughters were born to them, 2 that the sons of God saw the daughters of men, that they were beautiful; and they took wives for themselves of all whom they chose.
3 And the Lord said, “My Spirit shall not strive with man forever,
for he is indeed flesh; yet his days shall be one hundred and twenty
years.” 4 There were giants on the earth in those days, and also
afterward, when the sons of God came in to the daughters of men and
they bore children to them. Those were the mighty men who were of old,
men of renown.

Without foreseeing the impending end of their mirthful:
Also, look at Genesis 6:5-7:

5 Then the Lord saw that the wickedness of man was great in the
earth, and that every intent of the thoughts of his heart was only
evil continually. 6 And the Lord was sorry that He had made man on
the earth, and He was grieved in His heart. 7 So the Lord said, “I
will destroy man whom I have created from the face of the earth, both
man and beast, creeping thing and birds of the air, for I am sorry
that I have made them.”

According to David Guzik :: Study Guide for Matthew 24:
Life was centered around the normal things:

a. As the days of Noah were: Jesus explained what He meant by the days
of Noah. It means life centered around the normal things: eating and
drinking, marrying and giving in marriage. In other words, life will
be business as usual; reprobate perhaps, but usual.
i. Eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage: Bruce notes
that “Some charge these with sinister meaning: [eating], hinting at
gluttony because often used of beasts, though also, in the sense of
eating, of men…[marrying and giving in marriage], euphemistically
pointing at sexual licences on both sides.” Yet he comes to the
conclusion, “The idea rather seems to be that all things went on as
usual, as if nothing were going to happen.”
ii. We should also remember that the days of Noah were also marked by
violence and demonic oppression (Genesis 6:1-5).

We see continued in Genesis 6:8:

8 But Noah found grace in the eyes of the Lord.


Thanks, Jason_. My question is : Did Jesus suo moto use the term, or was he quoting from OT . If the latter is right, which portion of OT was he quoting. Gen 6:1-2 appears tobe a wrong candidate for the reason w.r.t Luke 2 .

Please read 'Luke 3' Genealogy

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Scripture says: "For as in the days before the flood, they were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, until the day that Noah entered the ark". This would seem to me like this behavior continued all the way until Noah entered the ark. (Matthew 24:38)

@KadalikattJosephSibichan I have read the genealogy. Perhaps consider Genesis 6:8 which says, "But Noah found grace in the eyes of the Lord." This would seem to indicate that these things were still occurring during the time of Noah.

Thanks, Jason_. Let us hear from other esteemed Users of BE. There are many who opine that Jesus was alluding to licentiousness which was rampant in Noah's times.

The answer must be taken in full context.
Certainly, the people before the flood were eating and drinking and marrying and giving in marriage. But none of those activities warranted God's decision to put an end to humanity as a whole. Jesus also came eating and drinking, and he even provided additional wine for a wedding!

The Son of Man came eating and drinking, and they say, ‘Look at him! A
glutton and a drunkard, a friend of tax collectors and sinners!’ Yet
wisdom is justified by her deeds.” - Matthew 11:19 ESV

The comparison to Genesis requires us to look at the reason given by God for the flood.

And God said to Noah, “I have determined to make an end of all
flesh, for the earth is filled with violence through them. Behold,
I will destroy them with the earth. - Genesis 6:13 ESV

Hmmm. Nothing here about gluttony, and licentiousness! Okay, so let's consider the points that Jesus made in the comparison.

No one will know the exact time when Jesus returns.


“But concerning that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of
heaven, nor the Son, but the Father only. - Matthew 24:36 ESV


No one had known when the flood would come.


. . . and they were unaware until the flood came and swept them all
away, so will be the coming of the Son of Man. - Matthew 24:39 ESV


Therefore, always be ready.


Therefore you also must be ready, for the Son of Man is coming at an
hour you do not expect. - Matthew 24:44 ESV


The reason is to be blessed at the judgment.


Blessed is that servant whom his master will find so doing when he
comes. - Matthew 24:46 ESV

Everything beyond these points is speculation and biazogesis rather than exegesis.
